# Internet Explorer opens jQuery Autocomplete on PageLoad

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11, jquery-autocomplete

We have a screen with lots of fields and some of them have jQuery Autocomplete attached to it. Now if the page loads, some autocomplete fields automatically pop out and contain the value that has been entered before. This only happens in Internet Explorer 11. Firefox (both Stable and Developer Edition) and Chrome don't do this.

Maybe it's just because I am searching wrong but I can't find anything and I need to have a quick answer for this.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking in Developer tools of IE : whether the Request headers of server call for the autocomplete function is taking the search keyword from cookies ?

Similar issue occurred with me. Clearing the cookie resolved the issue for me.

OR empty the field on page load :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#myinput').prop('value','')
});
```

Hope this helps